# How to construct literals in SAT solvers

Tags: solver, sat

I am study the sources of minisat and here there is a follow inline function

```
 typedef int Var;
 inline  Lit  mkLit     (Var var, bool sign) { Lit p; p.x = var + var + (int)sign; return p; }
```

which recibes as input a integer var (a integer of the DIMAC file) and return a literal p, I do not understand Why var is added with var and then added with sign? Could you help to understand that please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `p.x` is just a regular int, what seems to be happening is that `var` is mapped to either `2*var`, if `sign` is false, and `2*var + 1`, if `sign` is true. Presumably the purpose of this is that in literals, `p.x % 2` will tell you whether or not `var` corresponds to a negated or non-negated variable, with the even `p.x` corresponding to negated variables and odd `p.x` corresponding to non-negated variables. The original `var` is easily recovered by `p.x/2`. This function allows you to code an (int,bool) pair as a single int.

Comment: Thanks John but I looking fot this expression "p.x/2" in the minisat sources and I do not found this

Comment: Whether or not the expression `p.x/2` occurs in the source, it is a fact that both `var` and `sign` can be recovered from `p` given the code that you gave since it yields either an even or odd int depending on the value of `sign`. Perhaps the code has no need to recover `var` later (though that seems unlikely), perhaps it uses a shift operator, perhaps it uses an identifier other than `p` in some other section of code, e.g. perhaps as part of an array rather than an individual `Lit` value.